# How to target elements in another element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-selectors, siblings, closest

I want to target certain `<button>`'s in an element specific container on webpage.

Here is my situation:

**I am trying to `.show()` button's B4 and B5 by clicking button "B3".**

Here is my markup:

```
<tr>
  <td class="leftSide">
    <button class="b1" style="display:inline">B1</button>
    <button class="b2" style="display:inline">B2</button>
    <button class="b3" style="display:inline">B3</button>
  </td>
  <td>Some middle-ground content</td>
  <td class="rightSide">
    <button class="b4" style="display:none">B4</button>
    <button class="b5" style="display:none">B5</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
  $( '.b3' ).click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.b4').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).siblings('.b5').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).nearest('.b4').show(); // tried this but it throws an error
    $(this).nearest('.b5').show(); // tried this but it throws an error
    $(this).closest('.b4').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).closest('.b5').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).next('.b4').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).next('.b5').show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).parent().find(".rightSide .b4").show(); // tried this and it does not work
    $(this).parent().find(".rightSide .b5").show(); // tried this and it does not work
});
```

Is it possible to reach the buttons in the rightSide container?

Comment: They are under the different parent, so you have to find the parent first if you're trying to get those elements by using `$(this)`.

Comment: This is a bit weird. If you explain your situation we can try to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this way

```js
$(function() {
   $('table .b3').on('click', function(){
    
    // $(this).parent().nextUntil('rightSide').next().show();
    // $(this).parent().find(".rightSide").next().show();
    // $(this).next('td').next('td').find('.b4').show();
    $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').find('.b4, .b5').show();
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="leftSide">
    <button class="b1" style="display:inline">B1</button>
    <button class="b2" style="display:inline">B2</button>
    <button class="b3" style="display:inline">B3</button>
  </td>
  <td>Some middle-ground content</td>
  <td class="rightSide">
    <button class="b4" style="display:none;">B4</button>
    <button class="b5" style="display:none;">B5</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="leftSide">
    <button class="b1" style="display:inline">B1</button>
    <button class="b2" style="display:inline">B2</button>
    <button class="b3" style="display:inline">B3</button>
  </td>
  <td>Some middle-ground content</td>
  <td class="rightSide">
    <button class="b4" style="display:none;">B4</button>
    <button class="b5" style="display:none;">B5</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well that won't solve what I need to do because my web page has many `<tr>`'s -- rows -- so your solutions shows all B4 and B5 buttons on the page. That is why I am thinking I need to use `(this)`

Comment: Hi @H.Ferrence, i have updated the answer, what you are expecting solution

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you @whoami...it is very strange that your answer works in my script but (at)Kannan's does not. His works in jsFiddle though. I am selecting tis as the answer simply because it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about paths, like folders and such.

You have buttons inside `left` folder, and want to access buttons to the `right` folder. So from `left` folder you must go to the parent and start from there, something like this:

```
$(this).parent().find(".right .b4")
```

This is like doing `../right/b4`

Comment: Thanks @JorgeFuentesGonzález. I'll work on that and post back.

Comment: Tried `$(this).parent().find(".rightSide .b4").show();`. It did not work @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

I traversed to the grandparent of that element and i will perform a find on ".b4" class and will show that

```
 $( '.b3' ).click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parentsUntil("tr").find(".b4"));
  $(this).parentsUntil("tr").find(".b4").show();
});
```

Js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/174861/

Comment: So odd. It works in jsFiddle but not on my webpage... will dig deeper.

Comment: My bad maybe you are having some more dom element's i guess however i can see other guy solved your problem. Happy coding